Seeing a segfault when I try to evaluate a polynomial. What am I doing wrong?
I am trying to use the FLINT Fast Library for Number Theory (https://flintlib.org/) to evaluate a multivariate polynomial over the integers mod a prime p. My code seems to follow the documentation, but still results in a segmentation fault.
Here is a minimal example that reproduces the problem:
#include"flint/fmpz_mod_mpoly.h"

int main(){
   const char *x[4]={"d","m1","s","t"};
   fmpz *vals=(fmpz []){3,5,7,11};
   slong p=13,c=0;
   fmpz_mod_mpoly_ctx_t C;
   fmpz_mod_mpoly_t E;

   fmpz_mod_mpoly_ctx_init(C,4,ORD_LEX,&p);
   fmpz_mod_mpoly_init(E, C);

   fmpz_mod_mpoly_set_str_pretty(E,"-d",x,C);

   //this is the line that segfaults
   fmpz_mod_mpoly_evaluate_all_fmpz(&c,E,&vals,C);

   flint_printf("Solution is %wd\n",c);
   fmpz_mod_mpoly_clear(E,C);
   fmpz_mod_mpoly_ctx_clear(C);
   return 0;
}

The segmentation fault happens inside a function in the library, so clearly either there is a bug in the library itself or I'm using it incorrectly. I'm guessing the latter. What am I doing wrong?
Edit: Added a comment to identify which line the segfault happens on. I've also posted the call stack below:
Thread 0 Crashed::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libflint.19.0.dylib                 0x103747d05 fmpz_mod + 37
1   libflint.19.0.dylib                 0x103936dfc fmpz_mod_mpoly_evaluate_all_fmpz + 255
2   Ftest                               0x102640e98 main + 264
3   dyld                              0x7ff807368366 start + 1942


OT: Why is vals a pointer instead of an array?

As for the crash, where in your code does it happen? If you catch the crash in a debugger and walk up the call-stack until you come to your code, on which line does it happen? Please [edit] your question to add a comment on that line. Perhaps also copy-paste the whole call-stack (as text) so we can see the arguments.

@Someprogrammerdude I've added an indicator of which line it segfaults on, and the call stack. vals is a pointer instead of an array because the library asks for that argument to be an fmpz *const*, and doing it this way simplifies the interface.

@Matt: That comment tells me that you're not familiar with C. In C, arrays will decay to pointers where needed, but not the other way around.

How can fmpz_mod_mpoly_set_str_pretty know how many pointers there are in x? Online documentation seems non-existent. I'd expect the function to either take a size parameter or that the last pointer is a "sentinel" NULL value.

@Lundin, the library knows this from the polynomial initialization  stored in C, which contains the number of variables (4).

@MSalters can you explain what the difference is in this context? If I instead replace that line with the lines fmpz v[4] = {3,5,7,11}; and fmpz *vals= v; then the program still segfaults.

Are you compiling with warnings on? If so, what do they tell you?

The documentation is indeed lacking, especially in examples. That makes it very hard to understand if you're doing something wrong, or if this could be a bug in the library. I would go to the Github issue tracker and report it as a bug. If the developers are active, they will quite quickly tell you if you're doing something wrong or if it's a bug in the library.

@Matt: For instance, sizeof(vals) is not the array size, but the size of the pointer.

@Chris there are no warnings in the compiling stage with -Wall -Wextra -Weverything

On a personal note, the design of the library isn't the best... Take for example the fmpz type, which uses the second highest bit to indicate if the value is an actual value or if it's a pointer. This makes the integers smaller, and also breaks the contract that unused bits in a pointer should be left as zero, and might unexpectedly break at any time.

@Someprogrammerdude: A bit stronger: In portable C code, there are no unused bits in a pointer. FLINT assumes there are. "This relies on the fact that malloc always allocates memory blocks on a 4 or 8 byte boundary" (not actually a fact).

@Someprogrammerdude Yeah, mathematician code. Let's just say this was by far the most professional option available, and leave the implications to your imagination.

The vals parameter of fmpz_mod_mpoly_evaluate_all_fmpz has the type fmpz *const*. Looking at the source code, it iterates over the outer dimension, and passes vals[i] to another function which expects a fmpz_t. And the documentation says:

By default, an fmpz_t is implemented as an array of fmpz’s of length one

Therefore, you should make vals an array where each element points to a 1-element array:
fmpz *vals[4] = {(fmpz[]){3},(fmpz[]){5},(fmpz[]){7},(fmpz[]){11}};

Unfortunately you can't define this as a simple 2D array because that type won't be compatible with a pointer to a pointer.

see https://github.com/flintlib/flint/blob/main/src/fmpz_mod_mpoly/test/t-evaluate.c lines 43-62 for an example:
    ...
    vals = FLINT_ARRAY_ALLOC(nvars, fmpz *);
    for (v = 0; v < nvars; v++)
    {
        vals[v] = FLINT_ARRAY_ALLOC(1, fmpz);
        perm[v] = v;
        fmpz_init(vals[v]);
        fmpz_randtest(vals[v], state, 200);
    }
    ...
    for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        fmpz_mod_mpoly_randtest_bits(f, state, len, exp_bits, ctx);
        fmpz_mod_mpoly_evaluate_all_fmpz(fe, f, vals, ctx);
    ...

using FLINT_ARRAY_ALLOC to initalize the vals array

FLINT_ARRAY_ALLOC is just a wrapper around malloc. This approach will work, but performs a bunch of unnecessary allocations.

I hadn't found that example, that helps give an idea of how they thought this should be done. I ended up accepting @interjay 's answer because it's what I ended up actually using.
